# Accessing centralized store through useSelector

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have Login functionality as below -

```
function SignIn() {
 const loginInfo = useSelector(state => state.loginDetails);
 const iLoginCreds ={
    userName:'',
    password:'',
    isLoggedIn:false
  }
  
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [loginCreds, setLoginCredentials] = useState(iLoginCreds)
  
  useEffect(() => {
    alert("state changed : "+loginCreds.isLoggedIn);
    
  }, [loginCreds])
  
  function checkIfSignedIn()
  {
    axios.get(`https://localhost:44301/api/login/ValidateLogin`)
         .then(res=>{ 
           console.log(JSON.stringify(res.data));
           setLoginCredentials({
            ...loginCreds,
            isLoggedIn:res.data
          });
            dispatch(StoreUserAuthenticationStatusAction(res.data));
         });
  }
  if(loginInfo.isLoggedIn==true)
  {
    return (
      <MainPage></MainPage>
    )
  }
  else
  {
    return (
               ...
               ...
               <FormGroup>
                <Button style={{width:'100%',backgroundColor:"#FCB724",color:"black",fontWeight:"bold"}} onClick={checkIfSignedIn}  >Sign in using our secure server</Button>
            </FormGroup>
            )
  }
```

**Reducer Index :-**

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import {SaveLoginStatusReducer} from  "./LoginReducers"

export const reducers=combineReducers({
    loginDetails:SaveLoginStatusReducer
})
```

**Issue -**

When `if(loginInfo.isLoggedIn==true)` , which I am fetching from `useSelector` at the beginning , I want to render to `MainPage`. But somehow cannot see , data is been fetched from central store. Page is not getting rendered to MainPage eventhough the state is been updated.

I am able to get alert for `useEffect` I have used when state changes. It shows "true".

**EDIT 1 :-**

When I am using  `if(loginCreds.isLoggedIn==true)` , I am able to see `MainPage` , but when I try to retrieve it from store through `if(loginInfo.isLoggedIn==true)` , I dont get true.

**Edit 2 :-**

**Action.js -**

```
export const StoreUserAuthenticationStatusAction=(loginPayload)=>{
    return {
        type:'SaveLoginStatus',
        payload:loginPayload
    }
}

export const SetProductList=(productListPayload)=>{
    return {
        type:'SetProductList',
        payload:productListPayload
    }
}
```

**Reducer.js -**

```
const iLoginCreds ={
    userName:'',
    password:'',
    isLoggedIn:false
  }
export const SaveLoginStatusReducer =(state=iLoginCreds,action)=>{
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'SaveLoginStatus':
            return {
                ...state,
                user:action.paylod
            }
            break;
    
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code pattern looks bad, you have to make authGuard to protect private routes.
That should redirects to auth page if the user is not signed in.
Redirects to main page after sign in.

```
const handleLogin = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (user.email === email && user.password === password) {
      login();
      history.push("/main-page");
    }
  };

<Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) =>
        isLogin() ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/login" />
      }
    />
```